# Optimizing image size for quality display on image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-screen-support

I want to download image from my server and display it on an image view.
My main concern is to not damage the image quality on different devices (with different screen sizes, resolutions and densities)

I want to figure out exactly how to measure what image size i need to fit the image view keeping its quality

For the sake of the question,
Say i have an image view with 100dp * 100dp size what image resolution do i need to download in order to keep the quality for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi devices?

I already know how to get the resolution and desisty of the device

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager  windowManager = (WindowManager) m_context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    Log.d(Utils.TAG,"displaymetrics : Hieght: "+ height + " width: " + wwidth);


    switch (m_context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"Low desity");
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"medium desity");
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"high desity");
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"xhigh desity");
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"xxhigh desity");
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            Log.d(Utils.TAG,"xxxhigh desity");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure. But i think i read that Instagram uses 1080x1080 for square images. 
I am not an expert when it comes to this. But i would think that if a big app focused on images uses that resolution. I should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low density (ldpi): 75x75

Medium density (mdpi): 100x100, baseline

High density (hdpi) 150x150

Extra high density (xhdpi) 200x200

Extra x2 high density (xxhdpi) 300x300

Extra x3 high density (xxxhdpi) 400x400

See [Range of screens supported | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)

Comment: Thanks! Question about images in general, if the image on my server is defined as 300*300 is there any other aspect of the image which i should examine? somethign similar to density in android?

Comment: Not really.  The only thing you might want to think about is that JPEGs have a quality factor.  With a lower quality factor there is higher compression therefore smaller file size, but also more loss of accuracy in the image.  PNGs, on the other hand, are lossless.